# Moving recommendation request guidance

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that included a recommendation for games - and this was (correctly) flagged as off topic. I had made sure to read the ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, and it did not mention recommendations in any way. It was later pointed out that it appears in the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but hidden in some caveats at the bottom.

Can we move this guidance to the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page?

Answer (score 5):

We have no control over the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page. If you want control, then you should probably check out [this very old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73381/254466). Until then, the very first line of that page says...

> First, make sure that your question is [on-topic for this site](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The link leads you to the page that we *do* have control over, the bottom of which reads:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Board and Card Games Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. **We're not the right place to ask questions about:**
>
> - [...]
> - Game Recommendation/Shopping questions, this includes all questions that could be phrased like:
>
>   - Best game for ... ?
>   - Which game is like ... ?

I think that the message is quite clear, and does not need to be reworded or reorganized.

Answer (score 4):

"What types of questions should I avoid asking?" Is a generic page that is shared by all sites, we do not have any control over it. So no we cannot move that information to that page.

Restructuring the "What topics can I ask about here?" might not be a bad thing though, but I don't have any suggestions for edits to make at this time.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [following](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) could be restructured, to make it easier to conclude that game recommendations are off topic. I'm not entirely sure how, though.

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Board and Card Games Stack Exchange, **it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site**. We're not the right place to ask questions about:
>
> - Computer games, **try gaming.stackexchange.com**
> - Role Playing games, **try rpg.stackexchange.com**
> - Puzzles, **try puzzling.stackexchange.com**
> - Game Recommendation/Shopping questions, this includes all questions that could be phrased like:
>
>   - Best game for ... ?
>   - Which game is like ... ?

All of this is steering towards a list of alternative sites (that speak for themselves), except for the last bullet. Shopping questions are not on topic for any SE site, so it's not possible to list an alternative site here. Instead I think this should receive extra emphasis, for starters by giving it a separate paragraph.